# Waiting request located in middleware finished before rendering page

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router, nuxt.js

I have an issue here. I use Vue.js alongside with Nuxt.js.

I made middleware to implement the authentication. Here I use JSON Web Token. I have accessKey and refreshKey. The refreshKey is used to request the new accessKey when the accessKey has expired. So in the middleware I call the action that make the request to the API. Here's my code:

home/index.vue

```html
<template>
I'm protected resource
</template>

<script>
export default {
  middleware: 'authentication'
}
</script>
```

middleware/authentication.js

```js
import { isEmpty } from 'lodash'
export default async function({ store, redirect, app }) {
  if (isEmpty(refKey)) {
    //logout
  }
  if (isLogin && !isEmpty(accKey)) {
    // store auth data
  } else if (isLogin && isEmpty(accKey)) {
    // call action that make request with axios to the API
    return await store.dispatch('user/requestNewToken')
  } else {
    return redirect('/')
  }
}
```

My action:

```
async requestNewToken({ dispatch, commit }) {
    const refreshReq = await dispatch('refreshToken')
    if (!isUndefined(refreshReq) {
      await dispatch('setupAuthCookies')
      return refreshReq
    }
  },
```

But the app returns error. This is because the page is rendering before the AXIOS request is finished. How to prevent Vue from redirecting and rendering the page before my axios request (for getting new accessKey) has completely finished? Thanks.

Comment: Are you `await`-ing your responses within your middleware function?

Comment: Yes ```return await store.dispatch('user/requestNewToken')```

Comment: And does your store action return a promise?

Comment: I updated the question @Phil

Comment: I have the same dilemma; using `await` middleware, to wait for a return from an external server. The `await` doesn't seem to be respected? Then I get the subsequent error "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client". Another clue: Simply commenting out the `await` line makes everything else function normally.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your store first, then get user info/permissions etc then you have to register routes etc then i'll works fine :)

```
/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance. You may then begin
 * registering components with the application instance so they are ready
 * to use in your application's views. An example is included for you.
 */
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${ localStorage.getItem('auth_token') }`;
app.use(createPinia());
// getting user form token
const authStore = useAuthStore();
await authStore.getUser(localStorage.getItem('auth_token'));

import App from './App.vue';

app.use(Router);
app.component('app', App);
```